# LocationManager returning null after Android SDK update

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-play-services, locationmanager, android-5.0-lollipop

I've just had this error today after the release of the new Android SDK.
Whenever I try to access the last known position through LocationManager, it creates a NullPointerException.

This has never been an issue prior to this update, but now, on the day of the Android SDK update, it constantly throws me that error. I have updated the Android SDK and the Google Play Services but with no luck.

These are the offending lines. They are called in the OnCreateView of a fragment that holds only a map. They're used to establish the initial location. The line that causes the error is not the initialization of the manager but line that calls getLastKnownLocation on it.

```
 LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getActivity().getApplicationContext().LOCATION_SERVICE);
 myLoc = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
```

And the relevant error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.khakicrew.pickup.MapTab.onCreateView(MapTab.java:53)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:915)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1099)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:292)
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code referencing the activity to [onActivityCreated()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)) as just in this place the `Activity` is fully created.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    myLoc = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
    ...
}
```